# On Windows 8.1 with a dual-monitor setup, can I run the same Metro-style application on two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, microsoft-onenote

I'm using OneNote to take notes in class, and I'd like to see previous notes while at home and reviewing. The simplest way to achieve this I could think of would have been to have one instance of OneNote for each of my two monitors, but apparently I can't do that.

How would I do something like that?

OneNote also apparently can't print, and I lose my pen drawings when I send the page as an email.

Comment: Did you simply get the OneNote app from the Windows Store?

Comment: @MattD, it came preinstalled, but yes, we're not talking about the one that ships with Office (if it still ships with Office, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the Windows Store version of OneNote, that's a Metro only app, which unfortunately can't be run across two monitors at the same time. You might be able to mess with the snap feature of Windows 8/8.1 to get two instances running on the same display in split screen, but until Microsoft allows Metro style apps to run in separate instances across two or more monitors, it's not possible to do what you're looking to do.

However, if you have the ***desktop*** version of OneNote, which comes with Office (and is included free on Surface RT and Surface 2 systems), you can launch two instances of the desktop version, and display each on their own display.

Comment: I have a Surface Pro 1, if that makes any difference.

Comment: But are you using it in this case? Is that what's connected to your external displays? Can you even connect a Surface (any model) to an external display?

Comment: Yes, I am using it, and yes, it has a mini-DP on its right side below the power connector.

Comment: Unless your Surface came with full Office installed, or you bought it, you don't have the desktop version. The one from the Windows Store is metro only. This applies to Surface systems, as well as laptops/desktops running Windows 8/8.1. Hope you didn't take my previous question as cocky/rude, I genuinely didn't know as I've hardly tinkered with the Surface.

Comment: @MattD - So revise your answer.  You should clarify the reason both the desktop and the Windows Store application is required.  Its simply enough to explain, your unable to run Modern UI applications, on two separate monitors at this time.

Comment: @Ramhound Done, take a look at it. Sorry for not seeing that sooner, was answering things in a bit of downtime at work.

Comment: @MattD - Much better ;-)